# how to URL path translate

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, pathauto, drupal-path-aliases

my language is Arabic i want to use pathauto for clean URL but my problem is when use this module my URL is very long because mydomain.com/الشهور الأخيرة بشأن استحواذ and browser convert to UTF-8 char 
how to use Google translate for translate my title of node to English and replace in URL path?

thank you

Comment: Arabic text already is UTF-8. Or did you mean the browser percent-escapes it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you'll be interested in the [Transliteration](http://drupal.org/project/transliteration) module, which "english-ise" the non-english characters and then creates the URL.

Comment: i use Transliteration module but my problem is  url path not working with Transliteration module . i think Transliteration module used in rename of files and ... how to use Transliteration module in url path

Comment: It should work together (maybe you need to install the 2.0 version of pathauto). did you check their settings options?

Comment: ok i use pathauto 2.0 and now translate title but translate not readable . how to change setting Transliteration module